# How to better edit inline HTML in JavaScript files using WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I've seen [videos by John Lindquist](http://www.youtube.com/user/johnlindquist) using WebStorm to edit inline HTML in JavaScript files. He opens a special window where he edits the inline HTML as if it weren't inlined.

I tried to find a video where he does that but I couldn't.

How does he do that in WebStorm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the HTML fragment in your JS code tap Alt+Enter and select Edit HTML fragment.
[image]

Comment: What an awesome feature! Thanks a lot!!